# General Topology - Proving that the Slinky Line is Hausdorff but not first countable.

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. Prove that $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{N}$ is Hausdorff but not first countable.

I am not sure how to start this proof.

Some relevant information that is helpful:

The diagonal relation on the set $\mathbb{R}$ is a relation $\Delta_\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ st:
$$\Delta_\mathbb{R} = \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$$

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be a space and $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The set $R = (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \cup \Delta_\mathbb{R}$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$. $X / R$ is denoted by $X / \mathbb{N}$ and $p_R$ is denoted by $p_\mathbb{N}$. So, $X / \mathbb{N}$ has the quotient topology coinduced by $p_\mathbb{N}$. Also, $R = (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \cup \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $p_\mathbb{N} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{N}$ is the natural projection.

To prove that $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{N}$ is Hausdorff we must show that for any two unique elements in $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{N}$ there exist disjoint open sets in the topology such that each open set contains a unique element.

To show that $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{N}$ is not first countable we must show that there is not a countable neighborhood base at some element in the space.

Answer (score 2):

The only point where there may not be a countable neighbourhood basis is
the point where $\Bbb N$ is identified to. Call that $[\Bbb N]$. The open
neighbourhoods of $[\Bbb N]$ in $\Bbb R/\Bbb N$ correspond to open sets
of $\Bbb R$ containing $\Bbb N$. Let's construct a bunch of them as follows:
Let $\mathbf{a}=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of positive integers, and
define $U_\mathbf{a}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(n-1/a_n,n+1/a_n)$ and
$V_\mathbf{a}=\pi(U_\mathbf{a})$ where $\pi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R/\Bbb N$
is the projection. The $V_\mathbf{a}$ do form an (uncountable)
neighbourhood basis of $[\Bbb N]$. What we need to show is that given a countable
collection $\scr V$ of sets of the form $V_\mathbf{a}$, then there is another $V_\mathbf{a}$ which doesn't contain an element of $\scr V$. A variant of the Cantor diagonal
argument should give you that.